# Having trouble starting up tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm following the demo example provided at [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Getting-Started). I have confirmed that jquery is working properly. However, I tried recreating the demo and jquery.tablesorter.js is not producing any changes at all. The output is still a pure HTML text table.

What am I missing?

**myTable.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/myTable.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/__jquery.tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

 </head>

 <body>

 <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
  <thead> 
    <tr> 
      <th>Last Name</th> 
      <th>First Name</th> 
      <th>Email</th> 
      <th>Due</th> 
      <th>Web Site</th> 
    </tr> 
  </thead> 
  <tbody> 
    <tr> 
      <td>Smith</td> 
      <td>John</td> 
      <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
      <td>$50.00</td> 
      <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
      <td>Bach</td> 
      <td>Frank</td> 
      <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
      <td>$50.00</td> 
      <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
      <td>Doe</td> 
      <td>Jason</td> 
      <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
      <td>$100.00</td> 
      <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
      <td>Conway</td> 
      <td>Tim</td> 
      <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
      <td>$50.00</td> 
      <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
    </tr> 
  </tbody> 
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

**myTable.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
);
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? What's with the underscores in your file path?

Comment: Yes, ReferenceError: $ is not defined
js/myTable.js
Line 1

I'm pretty new at the debugging part. I'm not sure what this means. I mean this usually works on when I hide/show things using jQuery.

Comment: @MarcoLau you've failed to include jQuery, check the path.

Comment: @MarcoLau sorry, got it. Move jQuery inclusion BEFORE js/myTable.js.

Comment: @MarcoLau and tablesorter must be included before js/myTable.js, edited the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move jQuery and tablesorter inclusion before js/myTable.js:

```
 <head>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/__jquery.tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/myTable.js"></script>

 </head>
```